# textbox keyup event not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, keyup

I am using following code to update one textbox value txtUnitPrice based on other textbox txtQuantity ,both can be generated dynamically which is done.

```
    //update unitprice based on quantity of product and tax applied
    $('input').live('keyup', function () {
        var inputId = $(this).attr('id');  //get textbox txtQuantity id
        var rowNum = parseInt(/txtQuantity(\d+)/.exec(inputId)[1], 10); //get row id
        var productValue = $("#ddlProduct" + rowNum).val();
        var taxValue = $("#ddlTax" + rowNum).val();
        var unitPriceValue = $("#txtUnitPrice" + rowNum).val();
        var quantityValue = $("#txtQuantity" + rowNum).val();


        if ((quantityValue != " ") && (quantityValue > 0)) {
            $("#txtUnitPrice" + rowNum).val(unitPriceValue * quantityValue);
        }
        else {
            $("#txtUnitPrice" + rowNum).val(unitPriceValue);
        }

    });
```

Now problem arising in the code above is that when I even moving cursor forward or backward in the textbox txtQuantity then the value for txtUnitPrice is changing becuase which this event 'keyup' is firing and hence whole code is executed with the existing txtunitprice value and multiplies this again with the existing txtquantity which I dont' want Please can anyone help me regarding this . Thanks

Comment: code is executing everytime that is fine but value is changing everytime that is not fine(it should be as it is until you dont change value of text box), I got what you don't want but what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check to ignore the cursor movements like shown below

```
$('input').live('keyup', function (e) {
    if([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.which)){
        return false;//do nothing because the cursor keys have been pressed
    }
    //the rest of your code
});
```